# iAd works on simulator but crash on device(ipad)

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, iad

I am trying to integrate iAd to my app, here is what I do

1. Create a single view app(devices type **universal**) by Xcode 5.1.
2. Add iAd.framework to my project.
3. Import `<iAd/iAd.h>` in ViewController.h
4. Add `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;` in viewDidLoad method.
5. Compile and run the app on iPhone and iPad simulator

The app works well on both simulator and I can see the banner at the bottom of my app.

But when I test it on my iPad(running IOS 6.1), the app crashes, Here is what I got.

```
2014-04-19 19:25:56.409 TestiAd[12771:907] -[ViewController setCanDisplayBannerAds:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fd7b620
2014-04-19 19:25:56.413 TestiAd[12771:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController setCanDisplayBannerAds:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fd7b620'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x336442a3 0x3b4e497f 0x33647e07 0x33646531 0x3359df68 0xfb125 0x3546b595 0x354abd79 0x354a7aed 0x354e91e9 0x354ac83f 0x354a484b 0x3544cc39 0x3544c6cd 0x3544c11b 0x371555a3 0x371551d3 0x33619173 0x33619117 0x33617f99 0x3358aebd 0x3358ad49 0x354a3485 0x354a0301 0xfb3a5 0x3b91bb20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

I have got lots of similar question on SO, but many of them were related to running iPhone app as computable mode on iPad, but this is not the case, I am testing on a Universal app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is on the iOS version.
From the [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/canDisplayBannerAds): `canDisplayBannerAds` is introduced in iOS7 and doesn't exist on iOS6..
So, you may want to do :

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setCanDisplayBannerAds:)])
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks, it should be `if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setCanDisplayBannerAds:)])`

Comment: Mine device and simulator are all iOS 7 and above, but the if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setCanDisplayBannerAds:)]) return false.

Comment: @bagusflyer: is self a `UIViewController`?